# How to save an <input>-selected image/video across browser refresh and closure in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, video, local-storage

I'm using React with `localStorage` to save the paths to image/video files. The paths are correct since the images/videos display properly in their given components. The paths also save correctly to storage because when I pull from storage, I see they are the same as what was saved.

However, the image path only "lasts" for a few refreshes or back buttons, and then suddenly, the image won't be found anymore, even though the path is unchanged. The video is never "found" after any refresh or back button (even though the path is correctly fetched) — it always says the video can't be found.

If the browser is closed and reopened, neither image nor video is found anymore.

I get the path using an input component like so:

```
<input
  ref={inputRef}
  type="file"
  accept="image/*,video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*,audio/x-m4a,audio/*"
  name="image"
  onChange={(event) => loadFileFromDevice(event)}
/>
```

I save the path to both state and localStorage like so:

```js
const loadFileFromDevice = (event: any) => {
  let media = event.target.files[0];

  if (media === null || media === undefined)
    // Means you canceled
    return;

  let path = URL.createObjectURL(media);

  let isImg = media.type.indexOf("image") != -1;

  if (isImg) {
    setImgSrc(path);
    setVideoSrc("");
    localStorage.setItem(IMG_KEY, path);
  } else {
    setImgSrc("");
    setVideoSrc(path);
    localStorage.setItem(VIDEO_KEY, path);
  }
};
```

I initialize the state using the following:

```js
// Outside component
const getValue = (storageKey: string, defaultVal: string) => {
  const item = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  if (item === null || item === undefined || item.length === 0) return defaultVal;
  return item;
};

// Inside component
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(getValue(IMG_KEY, ""));
const [videoSrc, setVideoSrc] = useState(getValue(VIDEO_KEY, ""));
```

I render the image and video in the following components:

```js
<img src={imgSrc} width="100%" height="100%" />
<video src={videoSrc} width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay loop muted />
```

As mentioned, the path is fetched fine and renders the images/videos correctly as long as the browser isn't refreshed. If I do refresh, the images will still be found (usually) but not the video.

If I refresh a few more times or let a few minutes pass and then refresh, the image will no longer be found. If I close and reopen the browser, neither image nor video is found. The file locations have not changed.

Why can't I reload the image/video I selected after a refresh/back button/close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `localStorage` only has very limited space, it doesn't persist videos or large images well. Instead, using `indexedDb` is the solution.

Create a React hook as follows:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';


// OPEN THE DATABASE

const openDB = async (dbName: string, version: number): Promise<IDBDatabase> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);
      request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
        const db = (event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result;
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('images')) {
          db.createObjectStore('images', { keyPath: 'id' });
        }
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('videos')) {
          db.createObjectStore('videos', { keyPath: 'id' });
        }
      };
  
      request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        resolve((event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).result);
      };
  
      request.onerror = (event) => {
        reject((event.target as IDBOpenDBRequest).error);
      };
    });
};


// STORE MEDIA
  
const storeMedia = async (
    db: IDBDatabase,
    mediaId: string,
    mediaDataUrl: string,
    mediaType: 'image' | 'video'
): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const tx = db.transaction(mediaType === 'image' ? 'images' : 'videos', 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore(mediaType === 'image' ? 'images' : 'videos');
  
      const request = store.put({ id: mediaId, content: mediaDataUrl, mediaType });
  
      request.onsuccess = () => {
        resolve();
      };
  
      request.onerror = () => {
        reject(request.error);
      };
    });
};


  // LOAD MEDIA
  
const loadMedia = async (
    db: IDBDatabase,
    mediaId: string,
    mediaType: 'image' | 'video'
): Promise<string | undefined> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const tx = db.transaction(mediaType === 'image' ? 'images' : 'videos', 'readonly');
      const store = tx.objectStore(mediaType === 'image' ? 'images' : 'videos');
  
      const request = store.get(mediaId);
  
      request.onsuccess = () => {
        const result = request.result;
        if (result) {
          resolve(result.content);
        } else {
          resolve(undefined);
        }
      };
  
      request.onerror = () => {
        reject(request.error);
      };
    });
};


  // LOAD MEDIA TYPE
  
const loadMediaType = async (
    db: IDBDatabase,
    mediaId: string
): Promise<'image' | 'video' | undefined> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const tx = db.transaction(['images', 'videos'], 'readonly');
      const imagesStore = tx.objectStore('images');
      const videosStore = tx.objectStore('videos');
  
      const imagesRequest = imagesStore.get(mediaId);
      const videosRequest = videosStore.get(mediaId);
  
      imagesRequest.onsuccess = () => {
        if (imagesRequest.result) {
          resolve('image');
        } else {
          videosRequest.onsuccess = () => {
            if (videosRequest.result) {
              resolve('video');
            } else {
              resolve(undefined);
            }
          };
        }
      };
  
      imagesRequest.onerror = () => {
        reject(imagesRequest.error);
      };
  
      videosRequest.onerror = () => {
        reject(videosRequest.error);
      };
    });
};


// #### THE MAIN HOOK ####

export type MediaType = 'image' | 'video';

export interface MediaItem {
  url: string,
  type: MediaType
}

export type MediaSet = { [key: string]: MediaItem | undefined };

export const useMedia = (databaseName: string, mediaIds: string[], mediaDefaults: MediaSet|undefined) => {

  // Persist the value across renders
  const mediaRef = useRef<MediaSet>({});
  const dbRef = useRef<IDBDatabase | undefined>();

  // Needed to force useEffect in components using it to update
  const [media, setMedia] = useState(mediaRef.current);
  const [db, setDB] = useState(dbRef.current);

  const initDB = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("INITIALIZING DATABASE: ", databaseName)

    const database = await openDB(databaseName, 1);
    dbRef.current = database;
    setDB(dbRef.current);

    const loadedMedia: { [key: string]: MediaItem | undefined } = {};

    for (const mediaId of mediaIds) {
      const mediaType = await loadMediaType(database, mediaId);
      if (mediaType) {
        const loadedItem = await loadMedia(database, mediaId, mediaType);
        if (loadedItem) {
          loadedMedia[mediaId] = {
            "url": loadedItem,
            "type" : mediaType
          };
        }
      }
      
      if (!loadedMedia[mediaId] && mediaDefaults && mediaDefaults[mediaId])
        loadedMedia[mediaId] = mediaDefaults[mediaId]
    }
    mediaRef.current = loadedMedia;
    setMedia(mediaRef.current);

  }, [databaseName, mediaIds]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initDB();
  }, [initDB]);

  // If saveToDatabase == true, saves media immediately to database on file selection
  // Otherwise, returns handle information for use by component (allows a component
  // to choose and use a file but only save it to a database when desired (e.g. on a 
  // button click)) using saveToDB

  const handleMediaChange = async (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    mediaId: string,
    saveToDatabase: boolean
  ) : Promise<MediaItem | void> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        const mediaFile = event.target.files[0];
        const mediaType = mediaFile.type.startsWith('image/') ? 'image' : 'video';
  
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async (e) => {
          const mediaDataUrl = e.target?.result as string;

          if (!saveToDatabase) {
            // Return mediaDataUrl and mediaType
            resolve({ "url": mediaDataUrl,
                      "type": mediaType 
            });
          }

          else {
            
            if (!dbRef.current) {
              console.error("Database is undefined");
              resolve();
            }

            await storeMedia(dbRef.current!, mediaId, mediaDataUrl, mediaType);
            mediaRef.current = ({ ...mediaRef.current, 
              [mediaId]: {
                "url": mediaDataUrl,
                "type": mediaType
              }
            });
            setMedia(mediaRef.current);
            resolve();
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(mediaFile);
      } 
      else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  };

  // When saving outside of handleMediaChange
  const saveToDB = async (
    mediaId: string,
    mediaDataUrl: string,
    mediaType: MediaType
  ) : Promise<MediaItem | void> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      if (!dbRef.current) {
        console.error("Database is undefined")
        resolve()
      }
      else {
        await storeMedia(dbRef.current!, mediaId, mediaDataUrl, mediaType);
        mediaRef.current = ({ ...mediaRef.current, 
          [mediaId]: {
            "url": mediaDataUrl,
            "type": mediaType
          }
        });
        setMedia(mediaRef.current);
        resolve();
      }
    });
  };

  return { media, db, handleMediaChange, saveToDB };
};
```

The hook is then called in a component like so:

```
const { media, db, handleMediaChange, saveToDB } = useMedia("myDatabase", mediaIds, mediaDefaults);
```

`mediaIds` is an array of strings that serve as the keys for storing the selected image/video. Each image/video div should have its own key.

`mediaDefaults` is the default item each div should show prior to selection. If no default, could leave url as "" or undefined. It's an object of this form:

```
{ mediaId1 : { url: "path", type: "image" }, ...}
```

for each `mediaId`.

Components can then use the hook to select an image or video like this, storing it in a temporary variable so you only save it to the database on say a Save button click:

```
// Add temporary media state
const [tempMedia, setTempMedia] = useState<{ [key: string]: MediaItem | undefined }>(mediaFiles);

useEffect( () => {
    setTempMedia({...mediaFiles})
}, [mediaFiles])

const handleFileChange = async(
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    mediaId: string
  ) => {
    const result : MediaItem | void = await handleMediaChange(event, mediaId, false);
    if (result)
      setTempMedia((prevTempMedia) => ({ ...prevTempMedia, [mediaId]: result }));
  };
  
// IN RENDER RETURN STATEMENT:
  
<input
  type="file" 
  accept="image/*,video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" 
  onChange={(event) => handleFileChange(event, mediaId)} />
```

and when you're ready to save, make a call like this:

```
// Save media changes
await Promise.all(
    Object.keys(tempMedia).map((key) => {
      if (tempMedia[key] !== mediaFiles[key]) {
        const mediaType = tempMedia[key]?.type === "image" ? 'image' : 'video';
        saveToDB(key, tempMedia[key]?.url as string, mediaType);
      }
    })
);
```

To show an image or video, you'd make a call like this to show what's saved in the database (or use `tempMedia` if showing the temporary, not-yet-saved, file):

```
mediaFiles[mediaId]?.type === "image" ?
      <img src={mediaFiles[mediaId]?.url} style={imageStyle}/>
      :
      <video width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay loop muted src={mediaFiles[mediaId]?.url}/>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

So you are creating the ephemeral URL to the media - it's lifecycle is tied to the `document` object. After reloading the page, saved url is no longer valid - it is not pointing to the file anymore. Via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

> The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created. The new object URL represents the specified File object or Blob object.

I'd recommend using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) To achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

A URL created with `URL.createObjectURL()` points to an in-memory file, not the one on the hard drive of the user. And it has a limited lifetime, as they say on MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

> The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created. The new object URL represents the specified File object or Blob object.

A common way to keep files is through cached responses. For example, the below code would work in vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScirpt, which you could easily adapt to React:

```html
<input type="file" name="image" id="" />
<img src="" alt="" />
```

```js
const createResponseObjectAndSaveInCache = (media) => {
  const response = new Response(media, {
    status: 200,
    statusText: "Ok",
    headers: {
      "content-type": media.type,
      "content-length": media.size,
      "X-file": media.name,
    },
  });

  window.caches.open("cachename").then((cache) => {
    let name = response.headers.get("X-file");
    let url = new URL(`/${Date.now()}/${name}`, location.origin);
    cache.put(url, response);
    localStorage.setItem("media", url.href);
  });
};

const displayFromCache = async () => {
  const href = localStorage.getItem("media");
  const cache = await caches.open("cachename");
  let response = await cache.match(href);
  if (!response) {
    return;
  }
  let blob = await response.blob();
  document.querySelector("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  let media = event.target.files[0];
  if (media) {
    document.querySelector("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(media);
    createResponseObjectAndSaveInCache(media);
  }
});

// display cached media if there is on load
displayFromCache();
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out. One thing is the line `let response = await cache.match(href);` is throwing the error "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'URL | RequestInfo'." Thoughts? I'm putting `const href  : any` for now, will see if it works.

Comment: My pleasure! Yeah, I didn't release you were using TypeScript. And yes, as you did, just make it work and later worry about the type. Meanwhile, try using `cache.match(JSON.parse(href))` instead of `cache.match(href)`.

Comment: Hi @Elliptica! Were you able to implement it?

Comment: Not yet, something pressing came up and I had to pause. Thank you for checking! I'll be able to return to this in about a week, sorry for the delay in getting back to you as to whether it's working or not!